# why bpf program doesn't find info? choose wrong kfunc?

Tags: c, linux, bpf

I use kprobe/do_sys_open to observe something. I write a demo to open a file and read. I think when I execute this demo, bpf program can find these action, but from bpf_trace_printk, I can't find any info about my demo. Did I choose the wrong kernel function? or what?

bpf_program.c

```
SEC("kprobe/do_sys_open")
int bpf_program(struct pt_regs *ctx)
{

    __u32 pid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid() >> 32;
    char msg[16] = "";
    bpf_get_current_comm(msg, sizeof(msg)) ;
    // u32 uid = bpf_get_current_uid_gid();

    // const int dirfd = PT_REGS_PARM1(ctx);
    const char *pathname = (char *)PT_REGS_PARM2(ctx);
    char fmt[] = "@pid='%d' @pathname='%s' @ comm='%s'";

    bpf_trace_printk(fmt, sizeof(fmt), pid, pathname, msg);

    return 0 ;
}
```

openfile.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* fp ;
    char buff[255] ;

    printf("Pid %d\n", getpid()) ;

    fp = fopen("./test.c", "r") ;

    fscanf(fp, "%s", buff) ;

    printf("Read: [%s]\n", buff) ;

    getchar() ;

    fclose(fp) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Could you share the output you get? It's not clear what the issue is currently.

Answer (score 0):

The actual syscall involved in your demo is probably `openat()`, I'd try hooking on `kprobe/do_sys_openat2` instead of `kprobe/do_sys_open`.

See how `opensnoop` in BCC, for example, [hooks to both `open` and `openat`](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/libbpf-tools/opensnoop.bpf.c) to catch calls to both (using the syscall tracepoints rather than kprobes, but the principle is the same).